# I need a powersource based on locomotion (3V 20 mA)

Tags: power-supply, energy-harvesting

Dunno whether this is the right place to ask this but i'll give it a try.

I want my bicycle light to be powered on the sideways motion of my bike. For this i would need a device which is also in 'automatic' watches like the seiko kinectic (they do not require battery but winded up by the motion of the wrist).

Does such a thing exist in electrical form (the watch version being mechanical)? And if so, would the power be large enough for a LED to burn?

Thank you!

Comment: you would be better off with a solar panel and charger

Answer (score 5):

That won't work, you can't generate the needed power to light a lamp that way. It works for the watch because that uses about 100 000 times less power than the bicycle light.

What's wrong with your dynamo? If the problem is that you have to peddle harder, then the sideways motion to electrical power conversion doesn't help. There's the Law, more specifically the laws of thermodynamics. They say that you can't get power from nothing. For the dynamo the penalty for getting electrical power is to exert more mechanical power. Same for the sideways motion. If you would be able to create enough power for the lamp you would feel a mechanical resistance reducing the motion, so instead of having to peddle harder you'll have to exert this force sideways.

There's no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: hmmm ok you're right. The dynamo generates a lot of friction and noise which i would like to avoid. Also most dynamos are designed to provide much more power than a led requires i guess but i should explore different types i guess.

Comment: @jorrebor - modern dynamos usually produce little noise. You'll always have a little friction, but on my bicycle I find that I barely have to push harder with the dynamo on.

Comment: yeps i understand, but i also wanted to get rid off the dynamo since it requires wiring on my bike. The cleaner the better in this case. But i read on wikipedia that there is a manufacturer who powers bicycle led trough magnetic induction, at least the noise will be gone..

Comment: Try a bicycle with a modern hub dynamo. You won't even know it's there!

Comment: Aren't all dynamo's about magnetic induction? This particular part sounds like salesman talk.

Comment: I used to have an 'HR' dynamo on my peddle bike. High Efficiency in english. It was easily recognized by a larger wheel that turns the magnet inside. Because the smaller air gap inside and ball bearings compared to conventional dynamos it wastes much less energy and generates only a little bit of noise. As @drxzcl states, modern bikes have the dynamo fitted in the hub, this is an even better option, but more expensive as you cannot simply put one on an existing bicycle.

Comment: @jorrebor - it would be extra useful if you used the dynamo to charge batteries to smooth out the power used, e.g. no dimming lights when you stop. Also it would be very cool if you connected the dynamo to the brake arms so when the brakes are applied the dynamo "recaptures" energy (although that may not work well, would need to experiment a bit.
You said " dynamos are designed to provide much more power than a led requires..." so use more leds - how about a tailight or more white leds up front.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to modify a [shake-flashlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_powered_flashlight#Shake_type_design) to do this. This would of course rely on rechargeable cells so that energy could be generated and stored during daylight.

These flashlights use a generator consisting of a heavy magnet inside a cylindrical coil. When the coil is shaken, the magnet moves backwards and forwards within the coil generating electricity.

I'm not sure that you would get enough lateral motion whilst cycling to operate one of these but it might be possible to make a lower power, more sensitive version.

Comment: That could be the way to convert the motion to electrical energy. Unfortunately the main word is "shaken" (not stirred :-)). Slow motion like the sideways motion of a bicycle isn't fast enough.

Comment: @stevenvh - There are micro-power energy harvesting devices using EM or piezo generators around. But I admit that even if an 'in-between' design could be made it would take a long time to harvest sufficient energy to light the LED for a useful time. Personally I don't have any lateral motion whilst cycling - I'm *far* too lazy :)

Comment: If you had one of those funky single-fork bikes (I think Cannondale makes/made them), you could just zip-tie the light body to the spokes and the weight would rise and fall as the tire rotated.  You'd have to remove the LED and figure out some kind of slip-ring set-up to transfer the electricity from the body to wherever you mounted the light, but that could work (for suitably small values of "work", anyway).